# NZEC in CRAZYSK spoj

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code for the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/CRAZYSK/ in python.
I am getting NZEC error.Is it due to the constraint X<=2^64 or something else?

```
n=raw_input()
for x in range(0,int(n)):
    raw_input()
    a,b=raw_input().split() #X,N
    print (int(a)-1)/(int(b)-1)+int(a)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing that extra `raw_input()`? It seems there are no blank lines between the inputs. Output for test cases seems to be correct then.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks.It worked for this problem.
But I had considered the input as given in the question.
http://ideone.com/sI9zVe

Comment: But even the input in the question does not have newlines. Those lines are just laid out a bit spaciously. When you copy them into an editor, there are no blank lines.